# Express return 200 in browser but 404 with curl -I

Tags: node.js, http, express, curl, heroku

I have an express server which serve some static files.

When I make a request from my browser all is fine. But when I use cURL it becomes a little bit weird:

- `curl https://www.goukitok.com` : HTTP 200 with page content
- `curl -I https://www.goukitok.com` : HTTP 404 (see verbose logs below).

I need `curl -I` to work because my client need to promote this page via Google AdWords and Google performs a check before allowing him to create the ad.

My server is hosted on Heroku.

I cannot figure what is making that? Do you have some idea?

Thanks in advance!

---

**`curl -v https://goukitok.com`**

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.goukitok.com/
*   Trying 79.125.104.202...
* Connected to www.goukitok.com (79.125.104.202) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 597 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: www.goukitok.com (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: CN=www.goukitok.com
*    start date: Sat, 16 Dec 2017 23:42:00 GMT
*    expire date: Fri, 16 Mar 2018 23:42:00 GMT
*    issuer: C=US,O=Let's Encrypt,CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.goukitok.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Cowboy
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
< Last-Modified: Fri, 02 Feb 2018 10:00:37 GMT
< Etag: W/"33cc-16155f5f188"
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 13260
< Set-Cookie: sessionId=s%3Akeguyz6fxoKCQDHIGY2Nd9mBgzM1pdiw.WhMMw37PNfXdv%2FYdx93oOdyTYMuv9SfcrYY0yuBrZ2E; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 13 Feb 2018 13:52:09 GMT; HttpOnly
< Link: <https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js>; rel=preload; as=script
< Link: <https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum:400,700%7CNunito>; rel=preload; as=style
< Link: </static/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css>; rel=preload; as=style
< Link: </static/libs/animate/animate.css>; rel=preload; as=style
< Link: </static/libs/slick-slider/slick.css>; rel=preload; as=style
< Link: </static/libs/slick-slider/slick-theme.css>; rel=preload; as=style
< Link: </static/libs/fancybox/css/jquery.fancybox.css>; rel=preload; as=style
< Link: </static/libs/fancybox/css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css>; rel=preload; as=style
< Link: </static/libs/fancybox/css/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css>; rel=preload; as=style
< Link: </static/css/layout.css>; rel=preload; as=style
< Link: </static/css/components.css>; rel=preload; as=style
< Link: </static/css/responsive.css>; rel=preload; as=style
< Link: </static/libs/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js>; rel=preload; as=script
< Link: <https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1796165227077270&ev=PageView&noscript=1>; rel=preload; as=image
< Link: <https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDqCiEbDSYSs-Wn-MHsq5jaygV4aew3_Tc&libraries=places>; rel=preload; as=script
< Link: </app/static/css/app.e595d7bef36fb3598585be947d8eb42a.css>; rel=preload; as=style
< Link: </app/static/js/manifest.1b6260866eb9b8932450.js>; rel=preload; as=script
< Link: </app/static/js/vendor.9159aedaca9691925a48.js>; rel=preload; as=script
< Link: </app/static/js/app.238040a9cfecf8b392ea.js>; rel=preload; as=script
< Link: </static/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js>; rel=preload; as=script
< Link: </static/libs/wow-js/wow.min.js>; rel=preload; as=script
< Link: </static/libs/slick-slider/slick.min.js>; rel=preload; as=script
< Link: </static/libs/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js>; rel=preload; as=script
< Link: </static/libs/fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js>; rel=preload; as=script
< Link: </static/libs/fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.min.js>; rel=preload; as=script
< Link: </static/libs/fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.min.js>; rel=preload; as=script
< Link: </static/js/main.js>; rel=preload; as=script
< Link: </static/libs/parallax/jquery.parallax-scroll.min.js>; rel=preload; as=script
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Tue, 06 Feb 2018 13:52:09 GMT
< Via: 1.1 vegur
< 
..... My page content
* Connection #0 to host www.goukitok.com left intact
```

**`curl -Iv https://goukitok.com`**

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.goukitok.com/
*   Trying 79.125.111.38...
* Connected to www.goukitok.com (79.125.111.38) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 597 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: www.goukitok.com (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: CN=www.goukitok.com
*    start date: Sat, 16 Dec 2017 23:42:00 GMT
*    expire date: Fri, 16 Mar 2018 23:42:00 GMT
*    issuer: C=US,O=Let's Encrypt,CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.goukitok.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: Cowboy
Server: Cowboy
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Express
X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 2644
Content-Length: 2644
< Etag: W/"a54-jADpSsEjSg0qJ+/8y3dImxntFHg"
Etag: W/"a54-jADpSsEjSg0qJ+/8y3dImxntFHg"
< Set-Cookie: sessionId=s%3ADWjJv6A4KYHEJcSdoxMABFcVXc6L-093.2lROCz0XKPu5dI1wmSOKgB3Ch%2FbPJQVaaS58zHXhLi8; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 13 Feb 2018 13:54:59 GMT; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: sessionId=s%3ADWjJv6A4KYHEJcSdoxMABFcVXc6L-093.2lROCz0XKPu5dI1wmSOKgB3Ch%2FbPJQVaaS58zHXhLi8; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 13 Feb 2018 13:54:59 GMT; HttpOnly
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Tue, 06 Feb 2018 13:54:59 GMT
Date: Tue, 06 Feb 2018 13:54:59 GMT
< Via: 1.1 vegur
Via: 1.1 vegur

< 
* Connection #0 to host www.goukitok.com left intact
```

Comment: Does your node code response HEAD requests?

Comment: @PeterVC According to Express doc "The app.get() function is automatically called for the HTTP HEAD method in addition to the GET method if app.head() was not called for the path before  app.get()." So I would say yes

Comment: Looking at the two logs the only difference I see is the HEAD request.  Without seeing your code we can't tell if your overriding the default behavior.

Comment: @PeterVC I'm investigating this way. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out by enforcing the static path at the very beginning of my routing file. It was a problem of middleware order

As @PeterVC pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644762/express-return-200-in-browser-but-404-with-curl-i#comment84286443_48644762) my server didn't handle the HEAD requests (sent by cURL when using the `I` flag).

I just moved `app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist')))` to the top a my express router file.